# Is there a way to track historical averages of flight costs?

Tags: air-travel, budget, flight-data

Covid-19 has shaken up the flight industry, and I noticed some flights to far off tourist destinations that seem like great deals, e.g. US to Italy for $1000 round trip. If they are so good, I'd like to take advantage while possible; though it would be preferred to wait until Covid-19 is gone to fly. To help with the decision-making process, is there any database of historical flight costs, so I can truly check if these are good prices, or just the usual?

Comment: [How can I view the typical flight prices between two airports prior to the COVID-19 pandemic?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161355/how-can-i-view-the-typical-flight-prices-between-two-airports-prior-to-the-covid)